# My select query is very slow, I need insights on how to improve it

Tags: mysql, join, select, multi-select

I have a query that I use to retrieve table data. The query is very slow when there are more than 3-4 rows returned, and I don't understand why.

This is my query:

```
select 
        ig.id,
        ig.username,
        ig.created,
        ig.is_completed,
        ig.user_id,
        ig.is_error,
        ig.last_appeal_process_update,
        (unix_timestamp() - ig.created) as time_running,
        ig.is_deleted,
        ap.id as appealprocessid,
        (case 
            when ap.id is null then 0
            when ap.id is not null then ap.status
        end
        ) as current_status,
        ( select count(*) from appeal_process where ig_account_id = ig.id)
        as total_appeals
        from instagram_accounts ig
        left join appeal_process ap on ig.id = ap.ig_account_id
        where 
        (ig.username like CONCAT('%',?,'%') or ig.id like CONCAT('%',?,'%') or ig.username like CONCAT('%',?,'%')) and 
        ig.user_id = ? and is_deleted = 0 and 
        (
            ap.id is null or
            ap.id = ( -- WE SELECT ONLY THE LATEST APPEAL PROCESS
                select max(id) from appeal_process tmp where tmp.ig_account_id = ig.id limit 1
            )   
        )
        order by ig.username asc
        limit ?,?
```

**EDIT**

This is **EXPLAIN** query (although I have no idea how to read it tbh)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb5Hn.png)

This is **SHOW CREATE TABLE** for `instagram_accounts`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8o0Z.png)

This is **SHOW CREATE TABLE** for `appeal_process`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt4Tc.png)

Comment: include `EXPLAIN {query}` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the tables in the query in your question. The orderCol, orderDir are pretty important so some sample values would be useful. Which MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack Done! thanks for helping me on this.  I never knew about EXPLAIN by the way! I have updated ordercol with real case value, also MySQL version Is 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `instagram_accounts` you have critiera specific to `user_id`, `is_deleted` but also `username`. As you are also sorting by username the first fix is to add an index.

```
CREATE INDEX user_id_deleted_username ON
             instagram_accounts(user_id, is_deleted, username);
```

In `appeal_process` you are searching by `ig_account_id` both in the `JOIN` and `tmp` subquery:

```
CREATE INDEX id_account_id ON 
             appeal_process ( ig_account_id)
```

On the query, you are pulling the status on the maximum appeal process id for a user. Lets `GROUP BY ig.id` and that simplifies how to get the results as `MAX` and others are per group (changes in CAPs for emphasis):

```
select 
        ig.id,
        ig.username,
        ig.created,
        ig.is_completed,
        ig.user_id,
        ig.is_error,
        ig.last_appeal_process_update,
        (unix_timestamp() - ig.created) as time_running,
        ig.is_deleted,
        COALESE(MAX(ap.id),0) as appealprocessid,
        (SELECT status FROM appeal_process WHERE appeal_process.id = appealprocessid LIMIT 1) as current_status,
        COUNT(*) as total_appeals
        from instagram_accounts ig
        left join appeal_process ap on ig.id = ap.ig_account_id
        where 
        (ig.username like CONCAT('%',?,'%') or ig.id like CONCAT('%',?,'%') or ig.username like CONCAT('%',?,'%')) and 
        ig.user_id = ? and is_deleted = 0 
        GROUP BY ig.id
        order by ig.username asc
        limit ?,?
```

Comment: The query resolves in 0.3 seconds now whereas it would have taken ~4 seconds!

Comment: Compare the `EXPLAIN` output too. MySQL-8.0.18+ has [EXPLAIN ANALYSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) too. [indexing](mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing) is important :-) happy SQLing.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your problem comes from lack of indexes, it is necessary to index the fields used in the `WHERE` AND `JOIN` clauses.

Create an index for each of these fields:

`ig_account_id`

`ig.id`

`ig.username`

`is_deleted`

`ig.user_id`

`tmp.ig_account_id`

Comment: Keep in mind MySQL can only use one index per table (alias in the case of self-joins), so aggregate indexes need to be constructed [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).  Also primary keys are an index and implicitly at the end of secondary indexes. Thanks for your answer, needs a bit more knowledge/detail however.